# Richtextbox into Access in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to save richtextbox content to Microsoft Access in a vb 2008.

I have uploaded a rtf file to richtextbox. Now richtextbox have tables, paragraphs.

I tried richtextbox1.rtf, but when i am saving i am getting error as

"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033\deflangfe1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22 Estonia\rquote s economic growth c'."

Any suggestions.

Here is my code

```
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty

    connection.Open()
    cmd.Connection = connection
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text


    sSQL = "INSERT INTO assessment (a)"
    sSQL = sSQL & " values('" & t1.rtf & "')"
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Data has been saved")
```

Comment: Show your query, and make sure you use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your rtf information probably contains a single quote somewhere, which messes up your string and the database engine can't figure out what is the text anymore.

You need to use parameters:

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO assessment (a) values (@a)"

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", t1.rtf)
```

BTW, always use parameters to avoid SQL injection.  Someone can write somethine like `';DROP TABLE assessment` in your textbox, and guess what, your table would mysteriously disappear.  Parameters would protect your from that.

Comment: It works, perfectly, but one more problem started, my database is crossed 40MB after one record added, so i copied rtf file to my folder and saved new path in db. IS there any way we can load rtf file using path from access in Crystal report.

Comment: @Malluhitzz That's a different issue.  Click on the Ask Question link at the top and make sure to properly document the issue.